# Why my sessionStorage doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session-storage, sessionstorage

just short question, why this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style" href="style.css">

<script>

document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', sessionStorage.getItem('style');

</script>
```

Doesn't work??

I guess my session storage is right, becouse with developer tools i can see that item style has a value, and when i change this value with other code it works, style actually changes, but when i open site again, eventhough the session storage value is ok the style doesn't change...

Anything?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a closing `)`:

```
document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', sessionStorage.getItem('style'));
```

or to improve readability:

```
var style = sessionStorage.getItem('style');
document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', style);
```

Also make sure that you have previously stored a value in sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('style', '/foo.css');
```